# GestureBuilder source code not in my sdk directory?

Tags: android, sdk

This is a very stupid question but I can't find the Gesture Builder source code. I want to modify the gesture builder source code for an android application I'm working on. As far as I know it should be somewhere within my sdk folder. GestureBuilder is on my emulator so I know the code has to be in there somewhere. When I google it i'm told it should be in sdk/platforms/android-2.0/samples/GestureBuilder, but when i follow that path: sdk/platforms/android-19 there is no samples folder or Gesture Builder code anywhere to be found.

I downloaded the ADT Bundle from android, do I need to download extra sdk files? GestureBuilder is on my emulator so I don't understand why it isn't in my sdk directory.

Comment: [GestureBuilder](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/apps/GestureBuilder)

Comment: Thanks, do I just download that into my sdk folder? I just need to edit gesture builders xml file so I can build gestures for letters like t and f by adding an android:fadeOffset option.